# Concatenar inputs dinámicos a uno ya creado en PrestaShop1.7

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, prestashop

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenos días gente, estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Prestashop y resulta que añadimos unas secciones dináimcas como profesión que se ve en la imágen y resulta que a la hora de guardar se guarda el dato de profesión mas no los datos que he metido en los campos dinámicos, alguna idea de cómo podría concatenar estos campos al campo principal (Profesión) ?

Answer (score 0):

El name que definas en el campo de **Profesión** debe ser de tipo arreglo para que puedas leer todos los que se agreguen dinámicamente, eg.

`<input type="text" name="profesion[]" value="">`

Ahora desde donde lees el post del formulario en PrestaShop podrás obtener los valores de la siguiente forma:

`$profesion = Tools::getValue('profesion');`

Donde `$profesion` será un **array** con los valores de todos los campos de **Profesión**.